# Yii 1 query value changes when insert a value even if the query was excecuted before on a SOAP WS

Tags: php, web-services, soap, yii, yii1.x

I am calling a SOAP WS method written in PHP, that has to be called only once, the first time that is called it creates a record in the database that throws an error messages from the WS in case it is called again

the problem happens when I call the service, as it always takes the else path of the condition, even it is the first time is called, looking into the execution flow I see that when the $this->createRequest($params); it always creates the record and changes the $model value to not null throwing the error as it wasn´t the first time is call

my code:

````
public function wsMethod(){
$model = Certificate::model()->find('codeValidate = :code',[':code' => $params->codeValidate]);
if(!is_null($model)){
    throw new SoapFault(self::ERROR_VAL_3['code'], self::ERROR_VAL_3['message']);
}else{
    $this->createRequest($params);
    return ['code' => self::SUCCESS_VAL_1['code'], 'message' => self::SUCCESS_VAL_1['message']];
}
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code this ways:

```
public function wsMethod(){
$model = Certificate::model()->find('codeValidate = :code',[':code' => $params->codeValidate]);
  if($model){
    $this->createRequest($params);
      return ['code' => self::SUCCESS_VAL_1['code'], 'message' => self::SUCCESS_VAL_1['message']];

  }else{
      throw new SoapFault(self::ERROR_VAL_3['code'], self::ERROR_VAL_3['message']);
  }
}
```